# Max cut of a sparse graph with maximum degree of 2.

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

What is the time and space complexity of  the best algorithm to find Max cut of a sparse graph with maximum degree of 2.

Background: We have polynomial time algorithms for 2-SAT but for 3-SAT and above the problem becomes NP complete and no polynomial algorithms exist unless P=NP.

Similarly Max cut is known to be NP hard for graphs with maximum degree 3 or above.
What about graphs with max degree 2? Do we have algorithms with polynomial runtimes for them, similar to 2-SAT.

Comment: Is it also from some programming competition? ~_~

Comment: No, just wondering if there are ploynomial algorithms for Max cut of graphs with max degree of 2.